# Datafusion load BQ with XML 2003 worksheet data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have a system exporting data as XML 2003 Worksheet.  I need to load it to Bigquery through datafusion or any other process using GCP resources.
So

- Is it possible to complete this with DataFusion
- I have followed the process for XML transformation in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-5K4cxwGrc&feature=youtu.be.  So far I have reached a point where the header and data rows appear in different rows but same column.  I am not able to parse it any further(using Wrangler) to individual columns as it just keeps isolating the json key:value pairs in different rows but same column

As I am new to datafusion, appreciate some detailed guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using Data Fusion.

Basically, once you have the file (either uploaded directly or connecting using a source) and use the transformation XML to JSON, you can add a parsing operation for the JSON so it will be parsed into columns [1]. This will add another Transformation in the wrangler.

Additionally, I would suggest that you take a look at the documentation for Data Fusion in GCP which is very self-explanatory [2].

[1]- Column transformations ->  Parse -> JSON

[2]- https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  I have actually parsed the XML to JSON, as per the video link directions, and then segregated the data, stripping away the Excel MSXML notations to the point of having the data portions left in the column with tags.  Issue is the notations are not standard XML, or JSON and hence I am not able to isolate the data into separate columns.  You can try the same with any Excel 2003 XML format output file.